# Элементы на втором экране не отображаются

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Друзья, я в программировании нуль, но хотел бы разбираться больше. Начал смотреть лекции Тимофея Хирьянова, но пока я всё равно никакущий, не могу разобраться, в чём ошибка. Я был бы признателен, если бы мне немного рассказали, в чем моя ошибка.

Запускаются два окна, в одном окне пользователь вводит цифры (баллы), и нажимает кнопку. Во втором окне должны отображать баллы, и сумма баллов. Не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы оба окна из `Qt Designer` работали.

```
import sys
from tkinter.tix import Form

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel


class SecondWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_referee7 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.input_referee6 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.input_referee5 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.input_referee4 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.input_referee3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.input_referee2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.input_referee1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_sum2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1020, 700)

        self.label_sum2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 20, 300, 300))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_sum2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_sum2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(90)
        self.label_sum2.setFont(font)
        self.label_sum2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_sum2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_sum2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.label_sum2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.label_sum2.setLineWidth(10)
        self.label_sum2.setMidLineWidth(50)
        self.label_sum2.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_sum2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_sum2.setObjectName("label_sum2")

        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(43, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(179, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_5")

        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(315, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(451, 390, 135, 145))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(586, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")

        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(722, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")

        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(858, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")

        self.input_referee1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(43, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left; QFramer: WinPanel")
        self.input_referee1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee1.setObjectName("input_referee1")

        self.input_referee2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(179, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left; QFrame:WinPanel;"
                                          "border-color:  black;")
        self.input_referee2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee2.setObjectName("input_referee2")

        self.input_referee3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(315, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left; QFrame:WinPanel")
        self.input_referee3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee3.setObjectName("input_referee3")

        self.input_referee4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(451, 540, 135, 145))
        self.input_referee4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left")
        self.input_referee4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee4.setObjectName("input_referee4")

        self.input_referee5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(586, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left")
        self.input_referee5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee5.setObjectName("input_referee5")

        self.input_referee6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(722, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left")
        self.input_referee6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee6.setObjectName("input_referee6")

        self.input_referee7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(858, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left")
        self.input_referee7.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee7.setObjectName("input_referee7")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label_sum2.setText(_translate("Form", "35,7"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.input_referee6.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee4.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee2.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee7.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee1.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee3.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee5.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))



    def Extream_Value(self):
        q1 = self.input_referee1.text()
        q2 = self.input_referee2.text()
        q3 = self.input_referee3.text()
        q4 = self.input_referee4.text()
        q5 = self.input_referee5.text()
        q6 = self.input_referee6.text()
        q7 = self.input_referee7.text()

        l = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7]
        print('min(l) = ', min(l), 'max(l) = ', max(l))
        m = [num for num in l if num != '']
        try:
            print('l = ', l, 'm = ', m, '\n', 'Extream_Value m', m, '\n', 'min(m) = ', min(m), 'max(m) = ', max(m))
            if min(m) == self.input_referee1.text():
                self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee2.text():
                self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee3.text():
                self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee4.text():
                self.input_referee4.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee5.text():
                self.input_referee5.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee6.text():
                self.input_referee6.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee7.text():
                self.input_referee7.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            else:
                pass
            if max(m) == self.input_referee2.text():
                self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee1.text():
                self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee3.text():
                self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee4.text():
                self.input_referee4.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee5.text():
                self.input_referee5.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee6.text():
                self.input_referee6.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee7.text():
                self.input_referee7.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            else:
                pass

        except ValueError:
            print('l = ', l, 'm = ', m, '\n', 'Extream_Value m', m, '\n', 'min(m) = -;', 'max(m) = -')


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setFixedSize(800, 450)

        self.secondWindow = SecondWindow()

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QLineEdit{font-family: Gotham; font-size:20px; text-align : left}
            QLabel{font-family: Gotham; font-size:55px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left}
        """)
        self.label_sum = QLabel()
        self.lineEdit_referee1 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee2 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee3 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee4 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee5 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee6 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee7 = QLineEdit()

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_sum)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee3)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee4)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee5)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee6)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee7)

        self.lineEdit_referee1.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee4.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee4.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee5.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee5.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee6.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee6.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee7.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee7.setText(str('0,0'))

        self.pushButton_MainDisplay = QPushButton('Confirm')
        self.pushButton_MainDisplay.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30px')
        self.pushButton_MainDisplay.clicked.connect(self.passingInformation)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_MainDisplay)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def passingInformation(self):
        self.secondWindow.input_referee1.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee2.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee3.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee4.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee5.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee6.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee7.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        q1 = self.lineEdit_referee1.text()
        q2 = self.lineEdit_referee2.text()
        q3 = self.lineEdit_referee3.text()
        q4 = self.lineEdit_referee4.text()
        q5 = self.lineEdit_referee5.text()
        q6 = self.lineEdit_referee6.text()
        q7 = self.lineEdit_referee7.text()

        l = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7]
        e = []

        for n in l:
            if n == ',':
                e.append(0.0)
            else:
                e.append(n.replace(",", "."))
        l = e
        newlst = [float(x) for x in l]

        m = newlst
        m = [num for num in m if num != 0]
        m_tuple = tuple(newlst)

        print('\n\n', 'm_tuple = ', m_tuple, 'type(m) = ', type(m), 'type(m) = ', type(m_tuple))
        if len(m) < 3:
            self.label_sum.setText('введи значения')
            self.secondWindow.label_sum2.setText('')
        else:
            m.remove(max(m))
            m.remove(min(m))
            m1 = sum(m)
            m2 = str(m1).replace(".", ",")
            self.label_sum.setText(m2)
            l1 = str(m_tuple[0])
            self.lineEdit_referee1.setText(l1)
            self.secondWindow.label_sum2.setText(self.label_sum.text())

        n_tuple = list(m_tuple)
        for num in range(len(n_tuple)):
            if n_tuple[num] == 0.0:
                n_tuple[num] = ''
        print('type m_tuple[0] = ', type(n_tuple[0]))
        print('n_tuple = ', n_tuple)

        self.secondWindow.input_referee1.setText(str(n_tuple[0]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee2.setText(str(n_tuple[1]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee3.setText(str(n_tuple[2]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee4.setText(str(n_tuple[3]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee5.setText(str(n_tuple[4]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee6.setText(str(n_tuple[5]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee7.setText(str(n_tuple[6]))

        self.secondWindow.Extream_Value()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = MainWindow()
    demo.show()
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = SecondWindow()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный `Qt Designer`, **НИКОГДА**.

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Я предлагаю вам внимательно прочитать официальные рекомендации по использованию Designer и помнить, что никогда не нужно редактировать вывод `pyuic`
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html

Я не вникал в логику вашего приложения, а просто расставил все как оно должно быть.

```
import sys
#? from tkinter.tix import Form

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel


class SecondWindow_Ui(object):                                       # SecondWindow_Ui
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1020, 700)
#+++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
        self.input_referee7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.input_referee6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.input_referee5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.input_referee4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.input_referee3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.input_referee2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.input_referee1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_sum2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.label_sum2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 20, 300, 300))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_sum2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_sum2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(90)
        self.label_sum2.setFont(font)
        self.label_sum2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_sum2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_sum2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.label_sum2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.label_sum2.setLineWidth(10)
        self.label_sum2.setMidLineWidth(50)
        self.label_sum2.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_sum2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_sum2.setObjectName("label_sum2")

        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(43, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(179, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_5")

        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(315, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(451, 390, 135, 145))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(586, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")

        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(722, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")

        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(858, 390, 136, 145))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 35px; text-align : left")
        self.label_7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")

        self.input_referee1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(43, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left; QFramer: WinPanel")
        self.input_referee1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee1.setObjectName("input_referee1")

        self.input_referee2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(179, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left; QFrame:WinPanel;"
                                          "border-color:  black;")
        self.input_referee2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee2.setObjectName("input_referee2")

        self.input_referee3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(315, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left; QFrame:WinPanel")
        self.input_referee3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee3.setObjectName("input_referee3")

        self.input_referee4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(451, 540, 135, 145))
        self.input_referee4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left")
        self.input_referee4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee4.setObjectName("input_referee4")

        self.input_referee5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(586, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left")
        self.input_referee5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee5.setObjectName("input_referee5")

        self.input_referee6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(722, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left")
        self.input_referee6.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee6.setObjectName("input_referee6")

        self.input_referee7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(858, 540, 136, 145))
        self.input_referee7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Gotham; color: black;"
                                          "font-size: 25px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left")
        self.input_referee7.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee7.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee7.setObjectName("input_referee7")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label_sum2.setText(_translate("Form", "35,7"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.input_referee6.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee4.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee2.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee7.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee1.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee3.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))
        self.input_referee5.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))


#+++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
class SecondWindow(QWidget, SecondWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def Extream_Value(self):
        q1 = self.input_referee1.text()
        q2 = self.input_referee2.text()
        q3 = self.input_referee3.text()
        q4 = self.input_referee4.text()
        q5 = self.input_referee5.text()
        q6 = self.input_referee6.text()
        q7 = self.input_referee7.text()

        l = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7]
        print('min(l) = ', min(l), 'max(l) = ', max(l))
        m = [num for num in l if num != '']
        try:
            print('l = ', l, 'm = ', m, '\n', 'Extream_Value m', m, '\n', 'min(m) = ', min(m), 'max(m) = ', max(m))
            if min(m) == self.input_referee1.text():
                self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee2.text():
                self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee3.text():
                self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee4.text():
                self.input_referee4.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee5.text():
                self.input_referee5.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee6.text():
                self.input_referee6.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee7.text():
                self.input_referee7.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            else:
                pass
            if max(m) == self.input_referee2.text():
                self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee1.text():
                self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee3.text():
                self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee4.text():
                self.input_referee4.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee5.text():
                self.input_referee5.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee6.text():
                self.input_referee6.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee7.text():
                self.input_referee7.setStyleSheet("color: Grey")
            else:
                pass

        except ValueError:
            print('l = ', l, 'm = ', m, '\n', 'Extream_Value m', m, '\n', 'min(m) = -;', 'max(m) = -')
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setFixedSize(800, 450)

        self.secondWindow = SecondWindow()
        self.secondWindow.show()

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QLineEdit{font-family: Gotham; font-size:20px; text-align : left}
            QLabel{font-family: Gotham; font-size:55px; font-weight:bold; text-align : left}
        """)
        self.label_sum = QLabel()
        self.lineEdit_referee1 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee2 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee3 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee4 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee5 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee6 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_referee7 = QLineEdit()

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_sum)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee3)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee4)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee5)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee6)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_referee7)

        self.lineEdit_referee1.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee4.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee4.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee5.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee5.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee6.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee6.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee7.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee7.setText(str('0,0'))

        self.pushButton_MainDisplay = QPushButton('Confirm')
        self.pushButton_MainDisplay.setStyleSheet('font-size: 30px')
        self.pushButton_MainDisplay.clicked.connect(self.passingInformation)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_MainDisplay)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def passingInformation(self):
        self.secondWindow.input_referee1.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee2.setStyleSheet("color: red")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee3.setStyleSheet("color: blue")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee4.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee5.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee6.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        self.secondWindow.input_referee7.setStyleSheet("color: Black")
        q1 = self.lineEdit_referee1.text()
        q2 = self.lineEdit_referee2.text()
        q3 = self.lineEdit_referee3.text()
        q4 = self.lineEdit_referee4.text()
        q5 = self.lineEdit_referee5.text()
        q6 = self.lineEdit_referee6.text()
        q7 = self.lineEdit_referee7.text()

        l = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7]
        e = []

        for n in l:
            if n == ',':
                e.append(0.0)
            else:
                e.append(n.replace(",", "."))
        l = e
        newlst = [float(x) for x in l]

        m = newlst
        m = [num for num in m if num != 0]
        m_tuple = tuple(newlst)

        print('\n\n', 'm_tuple = ', m_tuple, 'type(m) = ', type(m), 'type(m) = ', type(m_tuple))
        if len(m) < 3:
            self.label_sum.setText('введи значения')
            self.secondWindow.label_sum2.setText('')
        else:
            m.remove(max(m))
            m.remove(min(m))
            m1 = round(sum(m), 1)                                                 # +++ round
            m2 = str(m1).replace(".", ",")
            self.label_sum.setText(m2)
            l1 = str(m_tuple[0])
            self.lineEdit_referee1.setText(l1)
            self.secondWindow.label_sum2.setText(self.label_sum.text())

        n_tuple = list(m_tuple)
        for num in range(len(n_tuple)):
            if n_tuple[num] == 0.0:
                n_tuple[num] = ''
        print('type m_tuple[0] = ', type(n_tuple[0]))
        print('n_tuple = ', n_tuple)

        self.secondWindow.input_referee1.setText(str(n_tuple[0]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee2.setText(str(n_tuple[1]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee3.setText(str(n_tuple[2]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee4.setText(str(n_tuple[3]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee5.setText(str(n_tuple[4]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee6.setText(str(n_tuple[5]))
        self.secondWindow.input_referee7.setText(str(n_tuple[6]))

        self.secondWindow.Extream_Value()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = MainWindow()
    demo.show()
#    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = SecondWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(Form)
#    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде, всё так! я смог код посмотреть только после работы. Спасибо, я не умею ещё применять класс в классе, не понимаю как это, теперь понимания стало больше. Везде поставил вам лайки. Если не так, дайте знать

Comment: @dutik все так, будут вопросы - задавайте.